# RStudio "Hit <Return> to see next plot:"

Tags: r, rstudio, par

**SORRY** Thanks for everyone's help. I was a dick in the comments. Sorry about that.

For the life of me I cannot get RStudio to stop telling me to "Hit  to see next plot:"

MWE:

```
data(women) 
fit = lm(weight ~ height, women)
plot(fit)
```

`plot(fit)` should print a 2x2 plot, but instead I have to view each subplot one by one.

What is driving me crazy is that I set `par(ask=FALSE)` and `devAskNewPage(ask = FALSE)`. I even downloaded the latest R and Rstudio. Nothing works.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something really obvious?

**UPDATE**. I started from scratch. I deleted R and RStudio. I deleted all my .R history files and cache. Re-downloaded R and Rstudio. But still: "Hit  to see next plot:"

**EDIT**. I should also point out that I had *never* before seen the message "Hit  to see next plot:". Suddenly it appeared and it won't leave.

Answer (score 4):

## Edit

Fixed answer to account for 2x2 layout:

```
fit = lm(weight ~ height, women)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(fit, ask=FALSE)
```

[image]

## Edit:

This is the behaviour as documented by lm's [plot method](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/plot.lm.html). The second example mentions the 2x2 plot. It's not a bug but the intended behaviour of `plot.lm`.

Comment: Nope. Tried that. It still plots each subplot one by one.

Comment: Ok, you deleted your original answer, which my first comment addresses. Re: your second comment, I know you can use `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))`, but `plot(m)` of a model `m` should *already* show a 2x2 plot. (My MWE is just some example I took from a stats intro lecture.) Besides, I don't need to `ask=F` inside `plot()`, since `par(ask=F)` is set globally.

Comment: Yes. I edited my answer to account for the 2x2 layout requirement. Maybe I still do not understand your question? Does this not fix your problem? No need to uninstall RStudio... sorry if this is not helping

Comment: try enlarging your plot window

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli tried, doesn't work. machine working fine otherwise. everything else in R and Rstudio working normally.

Comment: im getting Hit to see next plot if dont use `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))`. if i use that i get 2*2 plot.

Comment: I added a link to `?plot.lm`. The behaviour you are seeing is as intended.

Comment: @invictus *"`plot(m)` of a model m should already show a `2x2` plot"* That is not correct. `plot.lm` will show 4 separate plots, asking for <Return> to see the next plot. That's the default behaviour. If you did get a `2x2` plot before my guess is you set `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` somewhere earlier in your script/code.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a day to figure this out!!  I ended up calling par(), and setting ask to false:

```
par(ask = FALSE)
```

By the way, I did not invoke this change to the parameter so that it is TRUE.  I have no idea how I did that, as I had not known about it until now.

Cheers,

Jason :-)

21 February 2022 1249(AWST)